# JS value from option is not defined?

Tags: javascript

I only recently started learning JS, like few days ago...
Now i'm trying to do something like max calorie calculator for practice, which depends on age, job profile and body mass in kg
where you get values for job profile, and age 
so maxcalorie is something like = job * age * mass
and for job factor it says it's not defined (when i take job factor out job * age works fine)
here is my code:

```js
var activityFactor = '';
var ageFactor = '';
var maxCalorie = '';

function izracunaj() {
  var age = document.getElementById('age').value;
  var mass = document.getElementById('mass').value;
  var job = document.getElementById('job').value;

  maxCalorie = mass * ageFactor * activityFactor;
  if (age <= 3) {
    ageFactor = 1.9;
  } else if (age >= 4 && age <= 10) {
    ageFactor = 1.5;
  } else if (age >= 11 && age <= 18) {
    ageFactor = 1.2;
  } else if (age >= 19 && age <= 26) {
    ageFactor = 1;
  } else if (age >= 27 && age <= 30 || age >= 50 && age <= 60) {
    ageFactor = 0.8;
  } else if (age >= 31 && age <= 35 || age >= 45 && age <= 49) {
    ageFactor = 0.7;
  } else if (age >= 36 && age <= 44 || age > 60) {
    ageFactor = 0.6;
  }

  if (job === manager || job === programer || job === admin) {
    activityFactor = 100;
  } else if (job === soldier) {
    activityFactor === 200;
  } else if (job === sportsmen) {
    activityFactor === 300;
  } else if (job === lawyer || job === econom) {
    factorActivnost === 150;
  }

  document.getElementById('calories').innerText = maxCalorie;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <label>mass</label>
  <br>
  <input type="number" name="mass" value="" id="mass">
  <br>
  <label>age</label>
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="age" value="" id="age"><br>
  <label></label>
  <br>
  <select id="job">
    <option value="programer">Programer</option>
    <option value="admin">Administrativni radnik</option>
    <option value="manager">manager</option>
    <option value="soldier">soldier</option>
    <option value="sportsmen">sportsmen</option>
    <option value="econom">econom</option>
    <option value="lawyer">lawyer</option>
  </select>

  <p>Maximal calorie intake: <span id="calories"></span></p>

  <button onclick="izracunaj()">Get maximal calorie intake</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using `ageFactor` and `activityFactor` before you set them in the `if` blocks.

You also need to quote the strings `manager`, `programmer`, and `admin`.

You don't need all the `age >= XX` tests in the first `if/else if` block, since any value less than that would be handled by the previous `if`.

```js
var activityFactor = '';
var ageFactor = '';
var maxCalorie = '';

function izracunaj() {
  var age = document.getElementById('age').value;
  var mass = document.getElementById('mass').value;
  var job = document.getElementById('job').value;

  if (age <= 3) {
    ageFactor = 1.9;
  } else if (age <= 10) {
    ageFactor = 1.5;
  } else if (age <= 18) {
    ageFactor = 1.2;
  } else if (age <= 26) {
    ageFactor = 1;
  } else if (age >= 27 && age <= 30 || age >= 50 && age <= 60) {
    ageFactor = 0.8;
  } else if (age >= 31 && age <= 35 || age >= 45 && age <= 49) {
    ageFactor = 0.7;
  } else if (age >= 36 && age <= 44 || age > 60) {
    ageFactor = 0.6;
  }

  if (job === 'manager' || job === 'programer' || job === 'admin') {
    activityFactor = 100;
  } else if (job === 'soldier') {
    activityFactor === 200;
  } else if (job === 'sportsmen') {
    activityFactor === 300;
  } else if (job === 'lawyer' || job === 'econom') {
    factorActivnost === 150;
  }
  maxCalorie = mass * ageFactor * activityFactor;
  document.getElementById('calories').innerText = maxCalorie;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <label>mass</label>
  <br>
  <input type="number" name="mass" value="" id="mass">
  <br>
  <label>age</label>
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="age" value="" id="age"><br>
  <label></label>
  <br>
  <select id="job">
    <option value="programer">Programer</option>
    <option value="admin">Administrativni radnik</option>
    <option value="manager">manager</option>
    <option value="soldier">soldier</option>
    <option value="sportsmen">sportsmen</option>
    <option value="econom">econom</option>
    <option value="lawyer">lawyer</option>
  </select>

  <p>Maximal calorie intake: <span id="calories"></span></p>

  <button onclick="izracunaj()">Get maximal calorie intake</button>
</div>
```

Comment: It might have been it, but also other thing with string, what's important is it works just fine now! Thanks for trying to help!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using print statements whenever things aren't working out for you. In this case, I would do a `console.log(job)` to find out what I'm working with. I think using `job.value` instead of `job` when you're making logical comparisons will fix the problem, but I could be wrong. If I'm incorrect, I'll change my response later when I get home (in 6 hours). Good luck!

**Edit:** manager is not defined. Similarly the other job names aren't defined either. Make sure if you're comparing job to manager, you're comparing strings instead. For example, do `if(job === 'manager')`

**Second edit:** I found out he did use `job.value()` but is comparing `job` with variable names instead of strings.

Comment: He used `.value` when setting `job`.

Comment: Ty, that was it! Now it works fine.               
Cheers!